# Visual Studio always starts as Admin

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

If I start my german VS 2010 (Win 7 Ultimate, German) on one of my pcs it says, that it is started as Administrator. I'm in the group of Administrators on all my pcs. If I start it on my notebook (same configuration as described) the title-bar says "Micrsoft Visual Studio". Thats what I want.

On my workstation however it says "Micrsoft Visual Studio (Administrator)".

I already checked up following places:

1. I'm NOT logged in as Administrator.
2. Properties of the VS-Icon -> Compatibility -> "Admin-Option" is not checked.
3. Properties of devenv.exe (same as 2)

Whats wrong? Can VS level itself up for some reasons?

Comment: What's the shortcut target?  I assume there's no `runas` call?

Comment: The shortcut-target is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe". Your assumption was right :-).

Comment: Does it ask you for your username/password when you click the shortcut? What happens if you navigate to the .exe and double click (i.e. don't use the shortcut)?